# Initial Value is incorrect

Tags: javascript, html

I have a UI where the user enters a number into a text box, which adds commas after every three digits after the decimal point. (For example: 1000 would become 1,000 and so on...)

Initially when the user enters a number 1,200. The value inside the box is treated as 1 instead of 1200. But when I reenter 1200 inside the same box. The number becomes the correct value of 1200.

How can I fix this so that the value will be 1200 no matter what.

Comment: Are you using the `onchange` event?

Comment: You will need to post your code so we can see what's going on. Total shot in the dark though, I'm gonna guess you're using `parseInt` on the field's value, and `parseInt('1,200',10) === 1`

Comment: Suggestion: First, try to look for a comma, remove the comma, then execute the rest of your code as normal.

Comment: Along with Will's answer, I'd recommend adding an input mask on your UI, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're retrieving the value initially, use JavaScript's replace function remove all commas. For example,

```
var num = parseInt( myInput.value.replace(',','') )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was that I forgot to parse something.